# rx java buffer is losing items

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

I have a PublishSubject with this configuration:

```java
PublishSubject<Message> messageObserver = 
    messageObserver
    .filter(t -> test(t))
    .buffer(eventsSaveTimeSpanInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, eventsSaveCount)
    .subscribe(messages -> saveToDB(messages));
```

Different threads of my application are writing messages to this `PublishSubject` via `onNext()`.

As I see, the `buffer` underlying `ObservableBufferTimed.BufferExactBoundedObserver` is non thread-safe, because its onNext looks as follows:

```java
public void onNext(T t) {
            U b;
            synchronized (this) {
                b = buffer;
                if (b == null) {
                    return;
                }

                b.add(t);

                if (b.size() < maxSize) {
                    return;
                }
                buffer = null;
                producerIndex++;
            }

            if (restartTimerOnMaxSize) {
                timer.dispose();
            }

            fastPathOrderedEmit(b, false, this);

            try {
                b = ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(bufferSupplier.call(), "The buffer supplied is null");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
                actual.onError(e);
                dispose();
                return;
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                buffer = b;
                consumerIndex++;
            }
            if (restartTimerOnMaxSize) {
                timer = w.schedulePeriodically(this, timespan, timespan, unit);
            }
        }
```

To make the race condition case more obvious I set the `eventsSaveTimeSpanInSeconds` and `eventsSaveCount`params to 1 (1 event in 1 second).

The problem appears in this block:

```
synchronized (this) {
                b = buffer;
                if (b == null) {
                    return;
                }

                b.add(t);

                if (b.size() < maxSize) {
                    return;
                }
                buffer = null;
                producerIndex++;
            }
```

So, if two messages are buffering at the same time then first message fills the `buffer` and assigns null to buffer variable. New buffer will be initialized later after the synchronized block. If there is a race condition, when the `buffer` is null, the second message will not buffered because of the code:

```
if (b == null) {
  return;
}
```

Is this a defect or a corrrect buffer behavior? How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: "Different threads of my application are writing messages to this PublishSubject via onNext()"  <- that's the problem. Please read the [javadocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use a serialized subject if multiple threads want to call `onNext`:

```java
Subject<Message> messageObserver = PublishSubject.<Message>create().toSerialized();

messageObserver
.filter(t -> test(t))
.buffer(eventsSaveTimeSpanInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, eventsSaveCount)
.subscribe(messages -> saveToDB(messages));

// from any thread now
messageObserver.onNext(message);
```